# System Design: How can we handle a Load Balancer crash?

Tags: architecture, bigdata, load-balancing, amazon-elb

You probably know the principle of putting a Load Balancer that gets all requests sent to the server and then distribute the requests to the nodes/machines that available in the system. In this case, all the requests are sent to the IP address of the Load Balancer machine.

I wish to ask:

1. How do we handle a case where the Load Balancer itself crashes?
2. What can we do if the requests volume is so high that the load balancer cannot handle it? Can we put another load balancer? In this case, what will be the IP address that the requests will be sent to?